# How to determine available biometric authentication types in Dart and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-biometric, localauthentication

I need to determine the available authentication methods for mobile devices (iOS and Android), but [`local_auth`](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth) leaves some features to be desired. Specifically, the issue I am facing is that all attempts using the local_auth package return `BiometricType.strong` and `BiometricType.weak`, and not something specific like the enums in the package, such as `BiometricType.face` or `BiometricType.fingerprint`. I need the *specific* biometric authentication types.

The only testing environment I have available to me is android studio's emulator, and on each attempted emulated device, pin, pass, and fingerprint were set. I was hoping to see that `BiometricType.fingerprint` was returned and displayed.
Here is my test code:

```
`import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:local_auth/local_auth.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final LocalAuthentication _localAuth = LocalAuthentication();
  List<BiometricType> _availableBiometrics = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkBiometrics();
  }

  Future<void> _checkBiometrics() async {
    try {
      _availableBiometrics = await _localAuth.getAvailableBiometrics();
    } catch (e) {
      print("Error checking biometrics availability: $e");
      return;
    }

    setState(() {});
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Biometric Authentication'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Available Biometric Authentication Methods:'),
              for (var biometricType in _availableBiometrics)
                Text(biometricType.toString()),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}`
```

*Quick note: for those attempting to replicate this code in a fresh Flutter project, visit the bottom of the local_auth readme page so that the android and iOS integrations are included in the AndroidManifest.xml and info.plist, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

There is a modified version of the local_auth package on github that fixes the above issues. I can confirm it works on multiple android emulated devices of varying APIs.
https://github.com/ajinasokan/flutter_local_auth.git